# How can I ignore or address blank cells in an Excel function?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have 7 columns and I want to check if each value in the columns are the same.  However, each column does not have a value. I would like to create a function that says:

=IF("A  = B = C = D = F = I = J", Value of the cells, False) However, I want to ignore any blank cells, so it does not trigger a False.

[image]

The actual ID column should populate to: False, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Comment: Why not just sum them? and compare to the final correct result? 1+2+3+4+5+6+7 = 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer. I am using =if(max(range) = min(range), max(range), FALSE)

This works!

Comment: I posted the same solution at the same exact time as you!  Beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula, will work for texts as well:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A11:G11)=COUNTIF(A11:G11,LEFT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A11:G11);LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A11:G11))/COUNTA(A11:G11))),LEFT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A11:G11),LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A11:G11))/COUNTA(A11:G11)))
```